# how to exclude db entries associated with certain tags using ci active records

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, tags

I got 3 tables in mysql:

cards:

```
id  | name
1   | alpha
2   | beta
```

tags:

```
id  | name
1   | a
2   | b
```

tag_link:

```
id  | card  | id
1   | 1     | 1
2   | 2     | 1
3   | 2     | 2
```

I would like to retrieve all cards which DON'T include a certain tag. CI model:

```
function search($_tag) {
    $this->db->select('card.id');
    $this->db->join('tag_link', 'card.id = tag_link.card');

    $this->db->where_not_in('tag_link.tag', $_tag);

    $this->db->group_by('card.id');
    $query = $this->db->get('card');
    return $query;
}
```

For tag '2' this returns card '1' as expected. However, card '2' is wrongly returned as well due to the one entry in tag_link connecting card '2' with tag '1'.

I thought about getting a first array of hits using the above function and then subtract another array in php containing all the cards including the tag I'm not interested in.
However this solution feels very clumsy. What's the most efficient approach for this problem?

Thanks,
singultus

Comment: removing the join will get you the results i guess, try the below solution in active_record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [TheWolf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2679333/thewolf) 's answer and converting it to active_record. Remember sub-queries are not supported by CI (although library can be used)

```
  $this->db->select('id');
  $this->db->where('id NOT IN (SELECT card FROM tag_link WHERE tag IN $tags)', NULL, FALSE);
  $query = $this->db->get('cards');
```

Comment: nearly perfect, only: `$this->db->where('id NOT IN (SELECT card FROM tag_link WHERE tag IN '.$tags.')', NULL, FALSE);`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know too much about CI, but as an SQL query, this might work (pseudo code mixing SQL and php):

```
SELECT id
FROM cards
WHERE id NOT IN
(
    SELECT card FROM tag_link WHERE tag IN $tags
)
```

The subquery returns all card ids that include a certain tag. The main query then returns all the other card ids. (Note that subqueries can cause performance issues in very large tables and/or complicated queries)

Comment: If I had the necessary reputation you'd get +1 from me too for providing the general approach.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your table structure should have clear names link this

```
cards:
-------
id  | name
1   | alpha
2   | beta

tags:
------
id  | name
1   | a
2   | b

tag_link:
---------
id  | card_id   | tag_id
1   | 1         | 1
2   | 2         | 1
3   | 2         | 2
```

Then you can put an and condition to avoid other results. and provide the avoiding card. Otherwise answering question is useless.

```
function search($tag_id,$card_id) {
    return $this->db
        ->select('card.id')    
        ->from('tag_link')
        ->join('card','card.id = tag_link.card_id','INNER')
        ->where_not_in('tag_link.tag_id',$_tag)
        ->where_not_in('tag_link.card_id',$card_id)
        ->get()
        ->result_array()
}
```

This will generate this query.

```
SELECT
  card.id
FROM tag_link
  INNER JOIN card
    ON card.id = tag_link.card_id
WHERE tag_link.tag_id NOT IN(2)
    AND tag_link.card_id NOT IN(2)
```

As you see you are avoiding card 2 other wise you are bound to get all the cards that are linked to any id anyway regards less of the tag_id you provide.
[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2f04/1) is the fiddle to test

Comment: As far as i get it, your solution would require me to know beforehand which card ids to exclude (2. param of your function). As this is to be included in a search engine, I don't know which cards might have another tag beside the one I want excluded. However, a solution without a sub query would be favourable.

Comment: PS: The columns are actually named exactly in the way you proposed. The shorter names were a byproduct of the mwe.